# Remove or replace strings from batch output

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm querying a registry key to get a value using the command (example):

```
REG QUERY HKLM\Software\Foo /v Bar >>c:\Foo.txt
```

When opening the `Foo.txt` file, I get:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Foo
    Bar   REG_SZ    foo-bar
```

How can I remove or replace both the key-name (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Foo`) and the "`REG_SZ`"? (preferably using only batch)

Comment: I had an additional question, is there a way I can also implement:
if the key Foo doesn't exist, check if key Foo2 exists and display that one - if neither do, display an error. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications" /v "Paint" 2^>nul
        ^|find "REG_SZ"
    ') do set "data=%%a"
    >foo.txt echo(%data:REG_SZ=%
```

Execute the command, retrieve only the line containing `REG_SZ` and store this line into a variable. Then remove the unneeded data and save to the target file

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "data="
    for %%k in (
        "NoPaint" "Paint"
    ) do if not defined data for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications" /v "%%~k" 2^>nul 
        ^|find "REG_SZ"
    ') do set "data=%%a"

    if defined data (
        >foo.txt echo(%data:REG_SZ=%
    ) else (
        echo ERROR 
    )
```

Instead of directly give the key, iterate over a list of candidates until the variable that will hold the data is defined. At the end, if the variable holds data, adapt and echo, else show error

Comment: I had an additional question, is there a way I can also implement: if the key Foo doesn't exist, check if key Foo2 exists and display that one - if neither do, display an error. Thanks!